# Why does this pipe feeding a hot water heater dip down like this?

Tags: plumbing, water-heater, pipe

This is a cold water pipe just in front of the hot water heater it is feeding. Why is it shaped that way? What is its function?

[image]

Answer (score 44, accepted):

It is highly likely that that piping arrangement is made that way to facilitate the installation of a water softener. A water softener will have a need to accept a pipe with incoming hard water and another for the outflow of conditioned water to the rest of the residence.

When a water softener is installed the U shaped fittings at the bottom of those two pipes would be removed and replaced with a new setup that usually consists of three or four valves. The valve setup allows for bypassing the softener, allowing water into the softener and also a configuration to backflush the unit. These days the whole valve system is often all integrated into a control unit with solenoid valves so that the controller can manage the flushing under electronic control.

Comment: In fact, that is exactly what we intend to do, install a water softener in this home that has very hard water in the area. Thanks!

Comment: @Rob, did the plumber _know_ you were going to install a water softener?  This is cool, but it seems odd they would take the time to do this just incase someone might want to install a softener in the future.

Comment: It is actually not that uncommon when houses are built in areas with very hard water. Especially in instances where houses are built in larger developments and the builder may include a water softener option for the new home owners to purchase.

Comment: @JPhi1618 This is original to the house being built in 1997. The area is a small rural town with very hard water. We have to replace the hot water heater because it's knocking badly. My son bought the house just a couple of years ago.

Comment: I plumb many new homes with only softened hot water. This allows cold water to be used for drinking and cooking still with out introducing additional sodium which can be a problem for people with health issues such as hypertension.

Comment: If the allowance was for a water softener then why are there not shut off valves installed. Personally whoever's did this was a plonked. As the pipes are not even clipped to anything to secure them and to stop them vibrating.

Comment: No no, you still have at least 3 valves, *so you can remove the water softener for servicing* without downing the house. Separately, the softener also has its own set of bypass valves.

Comment: Is there any chance there use to be a water softener there and it got removed, along with the isolation valves? The previous owner might have just wanted to keep it all when moving away. That would explain the now silly setup.

Comment: @JeffreysupportsMonica Judging by the calcium build up and knocking the water heater now, I'd say, no, there was no previous softener. I'm no expert but the electric and plumbing throughout the house is very well done.

Comment: My guess, a plumber installed this pipe when the house was being built but the water softener hadn't arrived yet so this was a stopgap measure. Then either the homeowner decided against installing or the plumber quit. And as so often happens the stopgap became the status quo.

Comment: @JPhi1618 the plumber certainly knows when the town has hard water.

Answer (score 7):

Looks to me like a heat trap, intended to keep hot water from flowing back through the cold water inlet.

A connection for a water softener would be arranged so that all water to the house (with possible exception of the outdoor faucets and the kitchen cold) could be routed through the softener.  Softening just the hot water makes little sense.

Comment: Except that it protects the water heater from building up hard mineral deposits, which extends it's life.

Comment: @jmarkmurphy - And you don't want to extend the life of toilets???

Comment: Lime scale doesn't really affect toilets that much. Maybe the fill valve, but the heat in the water heater coupled with the minerals in hard water cause the problem. Cold water, not so much.

Comment: Additionally, the fill valve of a toilet is a cheap and easy replacement relative to a water heater (especially given the frequency of replacement, which will generally be less than once a year). Also, softened water contains sodium, which people with certain medical conditions may not wish to consume (whereas most people don't drink hot water).

Comment: @DoktorJ - Usually the sink cold water faucet is not softened, if it's practical to plumb it that way.  (Though this is more a matter of taste -- the "added salt" in softened water is inconsequential from a health standpoint.)  But most people want both the hot and cold water in their baths softened.

Answer (score 4):

Without knowing the rest of the layout, I can't be 100% certain, but there a few possibilities:

1. As others have mentioned, it could have been placed that way because the original owner intended to fit a "softener" or "filter".
2. Since the house is over 20 years old, its possible there was previously some other device fitted that has subsequently been removed.
3. It's possible it is designed to limit backflow, for example when the inlet pressure drops, or supply is turned off for maintenance.
4. Similarly, it could be designed to stop air bubble making their way into the heater and becoming trapped.

Answer (score 3):

@Michael Karas has it right. This [website](https://www.best-osmosis-systems.com/) has a [DIY](https://www.best-osmosis-systems.com/water-softener-installation-guide/) that explains things rather well, complete with diagram and YouTube video. They recommend 10ft of pipe between the water softener and water heater to prevent backflow of hot water into the softener, similar to @Hot Licks heat trap, but I personally would use a check valve, which allows flow in only one direction (e.g. *into* the water heater.)

If you eliminate the outdoor faucets and kitchen cold from water softener, as both @Hot Licks and the above website recommend, there isn't that much water usage left unheated, 2 or 3 toilets, the cold on 2 or 3 sinks and 2 or 3 tubs/showers, maybe an ice maker in the fridge and maybe a dishwasher (hot and cold), perhaps a clothes washing machine (hot and cold).

So, @Hot Licks, since we don't know anything about the provisioning for softened water to the remaining cold usage points (ice maker, toilets, etc.), I would bet there's an easy way disconnect them from the incoming supply and connect them to the softener.

Regardless, softening just the hot water still can make sense. The hard water in areas with limestone and chalk, dissolved by weakly acidic rain containing carbonic acid, gets its hardness from calcium hydrogencarbonate (CaHCO<sub>3</sub>)<sub>2</sub>. When heated, calcium hydrogencarbonate breaks down into CO<sub>2</sub>(gas), H<sub>2</sub>O (liquid, obviously), and calcium carbonate (CaCO<sub>3</sub>, solid), also called *limescale* in this scenario. This can clog pipes and encrust the heating elements of a water heater, causing poor heating efficiency and hastening the burnout of electric heating elements. In areas with hard enough water, by keeping energy usage down and preserving the life of the water heater, a water softener just for the water heater can pay for itself long before you pay off the mortgage.

Comment: The plumbing diagram on that site looks exactly like what we have. I'm hoping that the front of the house outside faucet is tapped into the mainline since it's closest to the water meter. Then I only need to worry about the back of the house outside faucet which is easy to get to and, hopefully, the plumbing is laid out with all this in mind. But I need to get to my son's house to double check.

Answer (score 1):

Could be the supply and return loop tied together from and old indirect water heater. Possibly once the house was fitted with gas piping the water heater was replaced, eliminating the need to be connected to the heating system.

Comment: Great answer, and welcome to the site!

Comment: No. It was not.